# How do you geocode addresses in R?

Tags: r, geocoding

I'm wondering how to geocode addresses in R Studio ? Is there a link to Google Developers API ?

Comment: Also dismo::geocode - nice because dismo also has gmap which gives raster objects.

Answer (score 5):

Use the R Library: ggmap. You will also need ggplot2 as well.

Here's example code:

```
library(ggmap)
geocode("Toronto Ontario", output = "latlon" , source = "google")
```

Comment: library detailed here : http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/geocode 

Description : geocodes a location using Google Maps. Note that in most cases by using this function you are agreeing to the Google Maps API Terms of Service at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms. Note that the google maps api limits to 2500 queries a day.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use the photon package to geocode from other sources like OSM
https://github.com/rCarto/photon

```
# installation 
require(devtools)  
devtools::install_github(repo = 'rCarto/photon')
```

> You can use the API for your project, but please be fair – extensive
>   usage will be throttled. We do not guarantee for the availability and
>   usage might be subject of change in the future. Have fun with photon
>   and make OSM grow!

There's a french tutorial here : http://rgeomatic.hypotheses.org/622